# How to connect between Spring Boot and MySQL on Docker with Docker-compose?

Tags: java, spring, docker

My Application Properties

```
spring.profiles.include=docker

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://dbwebrestful:3306/webrestful
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=webrestful
```

and my docker-compose.yml

[on this link](https://pastebin.com/vMmrA0N3)

but still error like this

[image]

what should I do to fix this issue ?

Comment: Apparently you are either using the wrong user or password or haven't provided the proper credentials (being allowed to connect remotely for instance).

Comment: 172.25.0.3 is the ip of MySQL server?  Have you checked is the access granted to all users?

Comment: in your docker-compose you have mentioned the User name as 'webrestful' but in your application.properties it is 'root'. Are both users present on the server?

Comment: If Docker compose is mentioned then embed its config in the question (no links), also it is not clear where both Springboot and MySQL live.

Answer (score 0):

If your docekr and mysql are on same instance then try this

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/yourdbname
```